# entrypoint.sh: exec: gunicorn: not found (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, gunicorn

I am unable to run a Docker container with a gunicorn entrypoint. I receive the error:

```
gunicorn_1  | /entrypoint.sh: 46: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

I'm building the docker images (gunicorn + nginx), hosting in a container registry and then pulling the image. I receive the error when I run `docker-compose up` on the server.

Dockerfile (gunicorn):

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 8000
```

Dockerfile (nginx):

```
FROM nginx:1.19-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    gunicorn:
        image: link_to_built_gunicorn_image
        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
    nginx:
      image: link_to_built_nginx_image
      ports:
        - 80:80
      depends_on:
        - gunicorn
```

Requirements.txt:

```
Flask
oauthlib
pyOpenSSL
gunicorn
```

I've looked at similar posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561783/entrypoint-sh-exec-gunicorn-not-found), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763029/gunicorn-not-found-when-running-a-docker-container-with-venv) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958066/gae-error-bin-sh-1-exec-gunicorn-not-found)) and checked the following:

- gunicorn is included in the `requirements.txt`
- Tried downgrading gunicorn version in `requirements.txt`

Additional information:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS OS hosted with Digital Ocean

Comment: Your error message mentions an `entrypoint.sh` script.  Is that part of the setup somewhere?

Comment: I don't have any reference to it in either my Dockerfiles or docker-compose file. I'm using `command`  in my docker-compose to start gunicorn